# Updating post with PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a sort of blog system, but I'm having trouble with editing an existing  'post' in the system. It is collecting the data from the database, and it displays it. But when I click the update button, I get this error. I've looked for it, checked my code couple of times, but I just couldn't find anything. This is the error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

And this is my code.

```
<?php //include config
require_once('../../includes/config.php');

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Bewerk</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/login.css">
</head>
<body>




<?php
//check for any errors
if(isset($error)){
foreach($error as $error){
    echo $error.'<br />';
}
}

try {

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT patient_id, voornaam, achternaam, leeftijd, lengte, gewicht, foto_url FROM patienten WHERE patient_id = :patient_id') ;
$stmt->execute(array(':patient_id' => $_GET['id']));
$row = $stmt->fetch();

} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>

<?php

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );

//collect form data
extract($_POST);



    if(!isset($error)){

    try {

        //insert into database
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE patiënten SET patient_id, voornaam = :voornaam, achternaam = :achternaam, leeftijd = :leeftijd, lengte = :lengte, gewicht = :gewicht, foto_url = :foto_url WHERE patient_id = :patient_id') ;
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':patient_id' => $patient_id,
            ':voornaam' => $voornaam,
            ':achternaam' => $achternaam,
            ':leeftijd' => $leeftijd,
            ':lengte' => $lengte,
            ':gewicht' => $gewicht,
            ':foto_url' => $foto_url
        ));

        //redirect to index page
        header('Location: index.php?action=updated');
        exit;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}

}

?>


<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
    <img src="../style/images/logo.png">
</div>
</div>

<div class="keuze_link row">
<p><b><?php echo $row['voornaam'];?> <?php echo $row['achternaam'];?></b> bewerken</p>
</div>

<div class="container">



<form class="toevoegen" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="voornaam" value="<?php echo $row['voornaam'];?>">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="achternaam" value="<?php echo   $row['achternaam'];?>">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="leeftijd" value="<?php echo   $row['leeftijd'];?>">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lengte" value="<?php echo $row['lengte'];? >">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="gewicht" value="<?php echo $row['gewicht'];?>">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="foto_url" value="<?php echo   $row['foto_url'];?>">
    <br>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Updaten!">
</form>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

If you guys wanna know more, or see more code, I'd like to hear it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT. for update.

```
//insert into database
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE patienten SET patient_id = :patient_id, voornaam = :voornaam, achternaam = :achternaam, leeftijd = :leeftijd, lengte = :lengte, gewicht = :gewicht, foto_url = :foto_url WHERE patient_id = :patient_id') ;
        $stmt->execute(array(
            'patient_id' => $patient_id,
            ':voornaam' => $voornaam,
            ':achternaam' => $achternaam,
            ':leeftijd' => $leeftijd,
            ':lengte' => $lengte,
            ':gewicht' => $gewicht,
            ':foto_url' => $foto_url
        ));
```

**Latest form for update**

```
<form class="toevoegen" action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="voornaam" value="<?php echo $row['patient_id'];?>">
    <input type="text" name="voornaam" value="<?php echo $row['voornaam'];?>">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="achternaam" value="<?php echo $row['achternaam'];?>">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="leeftijd" value="<?php echo $row['leeftijd'];?>">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lengte" value="<?php echo $row['lengte'];?>">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="gewicht" value="<?php echo $row['gewicht'];?>">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="foto_url" value="<?php echo $row['foto_url'];?>">
    <br>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Updaten!">
</form>
```

Comment: Why have you prepended your column names with `$`? Also, your query expects 7 parameters, but you only provide 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:patient_id is missing from the `$stmt->execute()` function. Please add it and try again.

Comment: Could you take a look at it now? I do not get an error anymore, but it doesn't update in the database as well.

Comment: Please post the latest `$db->prepare()` and `$stmt->execute()` for update here. I will take a look.

Comment: I've posted it under the rest of my question up here.

Comment: : is missing before patient_id. It should be `:patient_id`

Comment: Fixed that, but still not updating it in the database :/

Comment: Can you do `echo $patient_id; exit;` before your update statements and make sure you are getting the same $patient_id you are trying to update in db?

Comment: Right before the update prepare? Now I get a message about an undefined variable patient_id . But I just don't get that, since it can load patient_id in. Because if I echo it in the form at the end of the page, it displays the right patient_id.

Comment: I cannot see any field called `patient_id` in your html form. You should include `patient_id` in the form as a hidden input field or so. When you click on the update button, the field should be sent with the post request. `<input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="<?php echo $row['patient_id'];?>">`

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to update that in here as well. But anyways, tried that already. It gives me the undefined variable: patient_id.

Comment: Well, do a `print_r($_POST); exit;` right after `$_POST = array_map( 'stripslashes', $_POST );` and click on your update button. Post the result here.

Comment: Array ( [voornaam] => Casper [achternaam] => skaf [leeftijd] => safs [lengte] => safas [gewicht] => saf [foto_url] => https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/27705-200.png [submit] => Updaten! )

Comment: You are not getting `patient_id` in the post array. You should get it in the above pasted array. There is something wrong with the `patient_id` in the html form. I need to see your latest html form.

Comment: I've added it in the main post.

Comment: Dude, I cannot see `patient_id` in the `HTML FORM` in the question. Where is it? After which input field?

Comment: Okay, saw it. The line for `patient_id` field should be `<input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="<?php echo $row['patient_id'];?>">`. You have added the field name as `voornaam ` instead of `patient_id`.

Comment: Oooh man, I'm so flipping pissed at myself right now. Already sorry for your wasted time, totally forgot to adjust the name of the input. Again, sorry for wasted time and for the big help of course :)

Comment: No problem. Even though this is a very basic stuff, I just wanted to show you a very good debugging method. Use `echo` and `print_r()` as breakpoints to trouble shoot. Happy programming.

Comment: Alright, indeed a good way, thanks. Will definitely use this for debugging in future. Enjoy your weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

In your update query you forgot about `:patient_id` to bind

And yes, remove $ before column names.